# Azure: "Service does not exist" on actor call

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

I have an `IActor` that I want to call to do some simple reminder-based computation. It is called like so:

```
var actorId = new ActorId($"item_{resp.ResultValue.Id}");
var scheduler = ActorProxy.Create<IScheduler>(actorId, ITEM_SCHEDUER_URI);
try
{
    await scheduler.SetupReminderAsync(new ItemInformation()
    {
        EntityId = entityId.ToString(),
        Date = resp.ResultValue.AutoResolveOn
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

However, whenever the `SetupReminderAsync` method is called, I get an `HRESULT: 0x80071BCD: Service does not exist` exception. I'm not sure what this means as I can plainly see the Actor's service spin up in debug mode. I could really use some guidance on what's happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my `ITEM_SCHEDULER_URI` was not correct because I assumed an endpoint different than what was actually populated. After checking the `ApplicationManifest` I was able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you seeing an endpoint for the `ActorService` in the Service Fabric Local Cluster Manager?  I've seen this problem when I forgot to define an endpoint. If you're using the default `ActorService`, I believe it defines its own. But if you use your own custom `ActorService`,  You have to override `CreateServiceReplicaListeners()` and create one yourself:

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceReplicaListener> CreateServiceReplicaListeners()
{
    return new List<ServiceReplicaListener>(base.CreateServiceReplicaListeners())
    {
        new ServiceReplicaListener(c => new FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener(c, this)),
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This took me a while, but my problem was that I had entirely the wrong interface in the `ActorProxy.Create` call. Service fabric still registers the actor and it can be seen in the service fabric explorer, but don't be fooled.

Don't be like me, check for simple coding errors before going to scrutinise the manifests.